# How to Insert Conditional Incremental Invoice No in Mysql Query

Tags: c#, mysql

**I was unable to Insert Conditional Incremental Invoice Number at a same time in multi User Environment, It creates Duplicates Invoice Number in mysql.
Please Help me.**

Table Name : Table1

Column Name : ID,TYPE_ID,TYPE_NAME,INVOICE_NO
[Database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FttcX.jpg)

In this Table Table1 ,Column ID is Auto Increment.
I want Sequential Incremental INVOICE_NO on Every Insert Row.
It is Possible to using Following Query.

First to Get Last INVOICE_NO using "SELECT MAX(INVOICE_NO) FROM TABLE1 WHERE TYPE_ID=1" FOR SALES TYPE Entry.
THEN +1 TO NEW INVOICE_NO.

EXECUTE FOLLOWING Query "Insert into Table1 (TYPE_ID,TYPE_NAME,INVOICE_NO) VALUES (1,'SALES',NEW_INVOICE_NO)**"

This is working fine for me. but problem in multi user environment. if users are executes same query in a same time,duplicate Invoice_no
is generated. How to Avoid Duplicates Invoice_No?

It is working in Single User Mode. But Working in Multi User Environment.

Comment: If its a fork of mysql like MariaDB you might want to look at sequences and don't use such a table. On standard mysql if you don't have performance/throughput concerns here then [lock](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html) Table1. If there are not that many types think about giving every type its own table to generate the number. That would result in less locking.

Answer (score 0):

Handling multiple writes on the database is tough. One simple solution is to set the column for `INVOICE_NO` to be unique, so that no two invoices can share the same number.

You can do that by running:
`ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD UNIQUE (INVOICE_NO);` on your MySQL database.

Please refer to this for more information: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp

Comment: INVOICE_NO could not be unique in my requirement because it is conditionally unique with column type_id. for example if Type_ID is 2 then invoice_no may 3  and if type_id is 3 then invoice_id is also 2 may be. i want i one user will insert same query then other user will wait after first user will completed the query.